# Flow from Servlet to DAO Layer

Tags: servlets

I see that the Flow from Servlet to DAO Layer will be from

Servlet--->Business Delegate---->Service Locator  ---- >SessionBean -->DAO

If my Servlet is such a way that

```
public void doGet(HttpServletReq ,HttpServletRes )
{
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

EmployeeDTO.setUserName(uname);
EmployeeDTO.setPassword(password);
```

From Servlet , how can i call the BusinessDelgate ??
Do i need to pass this DTO Object to BusinessDelegate??

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass data transfer object to business layer. Based on given information I can not comment on exactly how to call Business delegate.

Comment: Thanks ,again if i am not wrong this Business Delegate contats the ServiceLocator know ??